# data pronoun doesn't work with dplyr::lst()?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

```r
library(dplyr)
zone <- c(rep(10,4), rep(20, 4), rep(30, 4))
value <- c(4.5,4.3,4.6, 5,5, rep(3,7)) + round(rnorm(12, sd = 0.1),1)
df <- data.frame(zone, value)
# Works
dplyr::group_by(df, .data$zone) %>% dplyr::summarise(var3 = dplyr::lst(value)) %>% dplyr::ungroup() %>% as.data.frame()
# Error
dplyr::group_by(df, .data$zone) %>% dplyr::summarise(var3 = dplyr::lst(.data$value)) %>% dplyr::ungroup() %>% as.data.frame()
```

Is there a way to fix this? Otherwise if I use bare name `value`, I get a warning in `R CMD check` that value has no visible binding for global variable `value`.

Comment: I don't think `lst()` is being updated.  In the `?lst` Life cycle:
The lst() function is in the questioning stage. It is essentially rlang::list2(), but with a couple features copied from tibble(). It's not clear that a function for creating lists belongs in the tibble package. Consider using rlang::list2() instead.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works with rlang::list2()

Comment: Hi, @JakeKaupp and Shubham. Will one of you please post the `rlang::list2()` solution as a formal answer, so it can be voted on and accepted? This will help remove this question from the list of unanswered `rlang` questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Jake
The `dplyr::lst()` function is in a questioning lifecycle stage. Therefore, the recommended function for this task is `rlang::list2()`.

```
dplyr::group_by(df, .data$zone) %>% dplyr::summarise(var3 = rlang::list2(.data$value)) %>% dplyr::ungroup() %>% as.data.frame()
```